# Where can I download pretrained weights for tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets?

Tags: tensorflow, transfer-learning

I see various places on the web and even in code from a homework assignment that just seems to know where pretrained checkpoints for various tf-slim models can be downloaded.

Example: http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.tar.gz

But if you visit download.tensorflow.org, there is no page returned so that you can pick and choose or just know the fully qualified URL to download the checkpoint files.

So if you don't know the name of the file (or what architecture you want to use), then how can you find these pretrained weight checkpoint files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start your browsing from the [`tensorflow/models`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) repository. When you open it, scroll down, and you see the [README.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/README.md). It has links to the four model categories: official, research, smaples, tutorials.

Let's examine the [official](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/README.md). It has three nets there, mnist, [resnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet), and wide_deep. Click on [resnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet), scroll down to the **Pre-trained model** section, and you will find links there to the pre-trained models. Note: not all models have pre-trained weights.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually just found this a minute ago.  Much appreciated for the quick turnaround.

Comment: Yes at the time I couldn't accept it until 4 more minutes had passed and at the time I was busy.  Thanks.